# How do I set the default Compose new email window position in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, 20.10

I would like to set the default window position of the Thunderbird compose new message window. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This post from [mozillaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1289595) might help.

Comment: Position of that window indeed normally should be remembered.

Comment: @vanadium It is not. It always reverts to showing towards top left.

Comment: @User24601 That article is very old and the information is no longer valid.

Comment: I know from your question. I only remarked that what you observe is not normal behavior.

Comment: This is not only a Thunderbird issue it seems. Most apps are not remembering the last used position. Maybe this is related to using a Wayland session by default.